# The unistd.h or stdlib.h when creating child processes in Linux

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I would like to know what are the differences between the headers unistd.h and stdlib.h when it's about creating child processes and establishing communications through pipes...

The system-call functions we use on these cases are, `read()`, `write()`, `wait()`, `pipe()`, `fork()`, `exit()`. And it seems that the library **stdlib.h** has them too, why all the examples here in **stackoverflow** or other sites include both headers?.

Demonstration:

Open your console and write **nano program.c**, paste the following code.
theng compile it with `gcc program.c -o program` and you will get the pid:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int pid;
   pid = fork();
   printf("EL pid %i\n", pid);
}
```

Comment: The first thing to know is that they're not LIBRARIES! And are you sure? AFAIK `read()`, `write()` ... etc, are only declared in *uinstd.h*, `exit()` though is declared in *stdlib.h*.

Comment: Yes completly sure!, i have a program that creates 10 child processes that recieve a message from a father and i'm including just the <string.h> <stdio.h> and <stdlib.h>, everything is working, pipe, fork, close functions i receive no error. I have ubuntu, and i edit the scripts with KWRITE.

Comment: Did you check the files content?

Comment: I just tried ceating the same program with nano using the same libraries and works fine too.

Comment: It has nothing to do with which text editor you used! I think you need to learn how things really work, and get away of how Windows OS teaches us they do.

Comment: There's a huge difference between the headers where functions are declared and the library which provides the function definition when the program is linked.   There's usually a single library that you do not need to specify on the command line that provides most of the functions in the standard C library and in the main POSIX libraries and platform-specific extension functions.  If you're using the maths functions, you often need to specify `-lm` as an extra library on the linking command line.  But headers are distinct from libraries — `<stdlib.h>` is a header, not a library.

Comment: I changed it thank you! @iharob

Comment: Doncs thanks! @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `exit()` is defined in the C Standard and its declaration is specified to belong in `<stdlib.h>`.

`open()`, `read()`, `fork()`, `pipe()` etc. are Posix system calls, not covered by the C Standard.  Posix specifies that most of them should be declared in `<unistd.h>` (though `open()` comes from `<fcntl.h>` instead).

Some older systems used to mix or duplicate these declarations, but modern environments do not any longer, in order to comply with these standards.

Note that the original C Standard allowed the compiler to guess unknown functions prototypes; C99 and C11 do not.  Your sample code will compile with an accommodating compiler and produce correct output because the system calls used have very basic APIs.  Compiling the same code with `-Wall -Werror -std=c99` should fail to produce an executable.

Programming this way is considered sloppy and no longer supported.  C has enough pitfalls as it is to not condone this kind of style any more.  People on Stack Overflow insist on writing correct code most of the time, hence the inclusion of the correct headers.

Answer (score 2):

Because those functions are declared in different header files.

E.g. [`exit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exit.html) is declared in stdlib.h , [`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pipe.html) is declared in unistd.h